# MSSQL geomerty.Filter(geometry) in postGis

Tags: sql-server, postgis

I have a stored proc in MSSQL with the line

`WHERE [geometryColumn].Filter(@geometryRegion) = 1`

How do I convert that into postGis syntax??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it (right after I posted the question)...

```
WHERE ST_Intersects(geometryColumn, geometryRegion) = true
```

> Bear in mind that there is a ST_Intersection and ST_Intersects. the one you need is "intersects"